# É possivel contar a ordem de palavras num campo via MySQL?

Tags: mysql

boa tarde!

Não sou um expert em mysql - por isso a duvida - q pode ate ser boba.

Tenho um campo num banco de dados onde é armazenado uma lista de preferencia de cores.

Ex:

```
Joao prefere: Azul, Verde, Vermelho.
Maria prefere: Verde, Azul, Vermelho
Pedro prefere: Azul, Verde, Vermelho.
```

no banco de dados tenho:

```
Usuario | Cores
Joao    | Azul, Verde, Vermelho
Maria   | Verde, Azul, Vermelho
Pedro   | Azul, Verde, Vermelho
```

O que preciso fazer:

Um Ranking mostrando quais as cores preferidas dos clientes.

Nesse caso cada cor seria pontuada de acordo com sua ordem.

Entao no nosso exemplo:

```
AZUL: teria 4 pontos (2x 1o lugar + 1 x 2o lugar)
VERDE: teria 5 pontos (2x 2o lugar + 1x 1o lugar)
VERMELHO: teria 9 pontos (3x 3o lugar)
```

A cor com MENOS PONTOS seria a preferida.

Existe alguma forma de se fazer esse ranking usando apenas comandos MySQL?

Eu consigo fazer isso via ASP - daria um trabalhinho - por isso a duvida se é possivel fazer isso via MySql, pra ver e é mais simples.

obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Isso deu um pouco de trabalho, mas vamos lá...

O centro da solução está na função [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) do `mysql`, que procura o índice de um valor numa lista separada por vírgulas. Basicamente ele faz um *split* e retorna a posição de um valor numa lista, exatamente o que precisamos.  Exemplo:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('Azul', 'Verde,Azul,Vermelho');
```

Retorna 2, e assim por diante

Um detalhe é que a lista não pode ter espaços, senão a palavra não é encontrada ('Verde, Azul, Vermelho', seria ' Azul' e não 'Azul'), por isso usei também a função [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) para remover os espaços.

Para resolver só com `SELECT`, criei uma tabela com as cores, assim é possível fazer um select nela e agrupar depois por cor, somando as ocorrências.

Se não usasse isso, teria de fazer uma CTE([Common Tabel Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax)) para resolver e talvez mais uma query, então acho aceitável criar uma tabela com os nomes das cores.

O resultado ficou:

```
select c.cor, SUM( FIND_IN_SET(c.cor, REPLACE(t.cores, ' ', '' )) )as TOT
 from cor c, teste t
group by c.cor
order by TOT;
```

Pode ver funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d3db0/17)

Tabela teste com os dados do seu exemplo, tabela cor apenas com as cores.